# Prevent users from accessing php files by typing it directly

Tags: php, security

There is a php file. I want to prevent users from going to that file by typing the url in browser. (ex: abc.xyz/test.php), but users will be able to access that php file when it's redirecting from the website itself. (ex: if user click on a link, it will load test.php)

is it possible?

Comment: It is, to a certain degree, albeit it's way too broad to cover in a answer.

Comment: Are there any tutorials about this out there?

Comment: See [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30390/how-to-perform-and-prevent-a-directory-traversal-attack). Also this has a term: `path traversal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is by using cookies (*Used by most of the popular websites*)

**test.php**

```
<?php
//Check if user has permission
if(isset($_COOKIE["allow_access"]))
{
    //delete access after visiting the page
    setcookie("allow_access","",time()-3600);
}
else
{
    header("location: index.html");
}
?>
```

**allow.php**

```
<?php
setcookie("allow_access","true");
header("location: test.php");
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
...
<a href="allow.php">Link</a>
...
</html>
```

Comment: @Epodax If you take a proper look at test.php, in the first if statement, we are removing access after visiting the page. Anyways, this is just a sample idea, there are many flaws here. You need to implement it according to your site needs.

Comment: Ah, so you do, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Upload a .htaccess file into your wp-content folder. Have a look if one exists already, then append this code to the end of the file. If you don’t have one, just create a new blank file and add this code to it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourwebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov)$ http://yourwebsite.com/ [NC]
```

Comment: Thank you. but it's not a wordpress blog. will this still work? will it need any changes as it's not for a wordpress blog.